How to connect to MySQL on WSL Ubuntu from the Windows host?
I am trying to connect to the MySQL server on my WSL2 Ubuntu 24.04.
I created a user in the following way inside Ubuntu:
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON cloud.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'

I even tried to create a user with the % wildcard:
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON cloud.* TO 'myuser'@'%'

Edit: I even tried to create another user with 0.0.0.0 because I read it is for remote access, but that didn't work either:
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'0.0.0.0' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON cloud.* TO 'myuser'@'0.0.0.0'

I then try to connect to the server from MySQL Workbench with the following details:
Connection method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: 172.26.15.15
Port: 3306
Username: myuser
Password: password

But I get:
Your connection attempt failed for user 'myuser' to the MySQL server at 172.26.15.15:3306

172.26.15.15 is my Ubuntu IP, I can even ping it from the Windows host
What am I doing wrong?

Are you able to login with that user via MySQL CLI in WSL?

Yes. Btw I also tried to create a user using CREATE USER 'myuser'@'0.0.0.0' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; because I read 0.0.0.0 means granting remote access but that also didn't work

Did you open port 3306 in WSL?

Oh I didn't, because I don't think I even have a firewall installed in the Ubuntu instance itself. But you mean I need to open port on WSL itself (not on Ubuntu)? If so, where do I check that?

Sorry, that wasn't clear.  I meant in Ubuntu.  Also, are you using WSL1 or WSL2?

Thank you, WSL2

Check MySQL is bound to an ip address.

@M.Behrens thank you, how do I do that?

Yeah, that's a good suggestion.  Especially if you don't have the fw running.

@Stackerito Is your MySQL conf in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf?  If so, there should be a line in that file that starts with bind-address.  Make sure that address is the Ubuntu instance's IP.

Try "ss -tulpn"

@M.Behrens Ok that is very weird! I changed the bind-address in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf to 0.0.0.0 and it got things moving! However I was getting a new error message: Access denied for user myuser@DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1.mshome.net, DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1 being the Windows host PC name! So I created a user with the following command: CREATE USER 'myuser'@'DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1.mshome.net' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';, and it worked! But why does WSL see my Windows host as DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1.mshome.net, and why is it using a real domain? Does Microsoft track us?

I found the answer - first of all I needed to edit the file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and change the line that shows bind-address to allow remote connections using 0.0.0.0:
bind-address 0.0.0.0 #originally it was 127.0.0.1

But I was still getting connection errors. This time however, I got a new error, telling me that the host that is refused is <PC_NAME>.mshome.net. So that meant that the WSL2 instance sees the host as <PC_NAME>.mshome.net
I then created a new user in MySQL and granted him permissions:
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1.mshome.net' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON schema.* TO 'myuser'@'DESKTOP-SMF8KJ1.mshome.net';

And that's it, I was able to connect to the WSL MySQL server from the Windows host
